# Problem getting Facebook pictures via iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, fbconnect

I'm trying to fetch events and profile pictures via Facebook connect on iOS,
I've made for example the request:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andDelegate:self];
```

and the response handling method:

```
(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {

    NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:result encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

and it won't work, the result variable type is NSConcreteMutableData and the url variable value is null.

help please :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NSConcreteMutableData is the actual image data, not its URL. All you needed was

```
(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the solution I've proposed earlier. Does it work for you?

[how to get user's facebook profile pic via fbconnect in my app iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784782/how-to-get-users-facebook-profile-pic-via-fbconnect-in-my-app-iphone/3784873#3784873)

Comment: Yes it did actually, but still there are cases i'd like to use the Graph API instead of FQL queries. Any answers for that? and Thanks!

Comment: I've experienced several problems while getting userpic via graph api when were developing a Facebook-integrated app. The facebook iphone sdk itself still has a number of issues, but it doesn't mean that there is no proper answer to your question :)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jonasman/JNSocialDownload

Try this lib, you can even get twitter