# Not receiving Facebook picture via Graph API

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to properly retrieve a user's profile picture using the current iOS graph method.

My call: `self.pictureRequest = [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/picture" andDelegate:self];`

What I do with the result:

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result{
    if(request == self.pictureRequest){
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
        image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:result];
        [self.view addSubview:image];
        NSLog("result is %@", result);
    }
```

So I'm just trying to get the profile picture right now. Result shows up as null in the console. I guess this means I'm not actually getting a result? (I tried `if(result) NSLog(@"got a result")` but it doesn't return, so I'm guessing a result isn't being sent back by fb?)

Any ideas? I also looked up a similar problem here but not sure what they do differently:
[Problem getting Facebook pictures via iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126678/problem-getting-facebook-pictures-via-ios)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well I can retrieve the user pic and other info like this .. try it

```
- (void)fetchUserDetails {
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"SELECT uid, name, pic, email FROM user WHERE uid=me()", @"query",nil];

    [fb requestWithMethodName:@"fql.query"
                                     andParams:params
                                 andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                                   andDelegate:self];


}//Call this function after the facebook didlogin
```

and in *request didLoad*:

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result 
{

    if([request.url rangeOfString:@"fql.query"].location !=NSNotFound)
    {
        if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] && [result count]>0) {
            result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        if ([result objectForKey:@"name"]) {

            self.fbUserName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];

           // Get the profile image
            UIImage *fbimage = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[result objectForKey:@"pic"]]]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the picture URL using requestWithGraph path (instead of requestWithMethodName like @Malek_Jundi provides) then see my answer here:

[iOS Facebook Graph API Profile picture link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444931/ios-facebook-graph-api-profile-picture-link/10493637#10493637)

Answer (score 0):

You can also get fb profile picture url by,

```
NSString *userFbId;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture", userFbId]];

NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
self.userProfileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```